# how to save Masterkey used for encrypting other passwords in a hash form using java

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to develop a password manager where a master key will be used to encrypt other passwords saved in the database. when a user runs the application for the first time, the application asks for the master password which generate keys saved on the settings for the encryption. In opening the settings file, the keys generated from the master password is saved in cleartext. I have attached the SignInSetting and Setting file, am not good in this area, I need help on how to save the keys in a Hash form.

```java
package one.pass;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;

public class Settings extends SerializableSett {

    SignInSettings d;
    byte[] v;

    Settings(String N_db, String Mpwd, byte[] salt, int it_counter) throws Exception{
        d=new SignInSettings();
        d.DS="DSA";
        d.KDF="PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
        d.salt=salt;
        d.it_counter=it_counter;

       // d.MasterKey=MyUtils.KDF(Mpwd, salt, it_counter, d.KDF);
          d.MasterKey=MyUtils.KDF(Mpwd, salt, it_counter, d.KDF);
        v=extract(N_db, Mpwd);
    }

    private byte[] extract(String N_db, String Mpwd) throws Exception{
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("DSA");
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
        KeyPair dsakp=kpg.genKeyPair();
        d.PublicKey = dsakp.getPublic();
        s.initSign(dsakp.getPrivate());
        Path p = Paths.get(N_db+"_sett.ser");
        d.save(p);
        byte[] dhpkb=Files.readAllBytes(p);
        s.update(dhpkb);
        byte[] dhsb=s.sign();
        // Performing the hash using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256
        SecretKey dks=MyUtils.KDF(Mpwd, d.salt, d.it_counter, "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        return MyUtils.Sign_Encoding(dhsb, dks);
    }


    public boolean ret_V(String N_db, String Mpwd) throws Exception{
        // Decoding to enable key verification using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256
        SecretKey key=MyUtils.KDF(Mpwd, d.salt, d.it_counter, "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        byte[] sign = MyUtils.Sign_Decoding(v, key);
        // getting the pair key to sign the generated public key with the private key
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("DSA");
        s.initVerify(d.PublicKey);
        Path p = Paths.get(N_db+"_sett.ser");
        byte[] dhpkb=Files.readAllBytes(p);
        s.update(dhpkb);
        return s.verify(sign);
    }

    SecretKey ret_Privatekey() {
        return d.MasterKey;
        //return MyUtils.Sign_Encoding(, dks);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String string_s;
        string_s= Arrays.toString(d.salt);
        string_s=string_s+d.it_counter;
        string_s=string_s+Arrays.toString(d.MasterKey.getEncoded());
        return string_s;
    }

}
```

```java
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.nio.file.Path;

//parametrs to link the database

public class SignInSettings extends SerializableSett{

    String KDF;
    String DS;
    byte[] salt;
    int it_counter;
    SecretKey MasterKey; 
    PublicKey PublicKey;

    static SignInSettings load(Path path) {
        Object obj = SerializableSett.load(path);
        return (SignInSettings) obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are "master password" and "master key" the same thing?

Comment: The Master key is generated from the master password to do the signing in